# BinaryTree ADP implementation in Java - How does the insert work?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, abstract-data-type

I have problems understanding the BinaryTree ADT, especially the Insertion method.

Most implementations I find in the internet, have two parameters, first an existing node and second the data that is to be inserted and work like "If the data is smaller than the nodes data, either add it as a left node or call insert recursively for the left node, otherwise do the same on the right side.

Is that comparison really necessary for a normal binary tree (not a search binaryTree)? Cause I want to implement a generic tree, the values might not be that easily comparable.

Tree Interface

```
public interface IBinaryTree<E> {

    public IBinaryTreeNode<E> getRoot();

    public Boolean isEmpty();

    public void insert(E data);
}
```

TreeNode Interface

```
public interface IBinaryTreeNode<E> {       
    public IBinaryTreeNode<E> getLeftNode();
    public IBinaryTreeNode<E> getRightNode();
    public E getData();

    public void setData(E data);
    public void setLeftNode(IBinaryTreeNode<E> node);
    public void setRightNode(IBinaryTreeNode<E> node);

    public IBinaryTreeNode<E> inorderFind(E data);
    public IBinaryTreeNode<E> preorderFind(E data);
    public IBinaryTreeNode<E> postorderFind(E data);

}
```

TreeNode Implementation

```
public class BinaryTreeNode<E> implements IBinaryTreeNode<E> {

    private IBinaryTreeNode<E> left;
    private IBinaryTreeNode<E> right;
    E data;


    @Override
    public IBinaryTreeNode<E> getLeftNode() {
        return left;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinaryTreeNode<E> getRightNode() {
        return right;
    }

    @Override
    public E getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public void setData(E data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLeftNode(IBinaryTreeNode<E> node) {
        left = node;
    }

    @Override
    public void setRightNode(IBinaryTreeNode<E> node) {
        right = node;

    }


    // Inorder search (Left tree --> Node --> Right tree)
    @Override
    public IBinaryTreeNode<E> inorderFind(E data) {
        if(left != null){
            IBinaryTreeNode<E> leftResult = this.left.inorderFind(data);
            if(leftResult != null)
                return leftResult;
        }
        if(this.data.equals(data))
            return this;

        if(right != null){
            IBinaryTreeNode<E> rightResult = this.right.inorderFind(data);
            if(rightResult != null)
                return rightResult;
        }

        return null;
    }

    // Preorder search (Node --> Left tree --> Right tree)
    @Override
    public IBinaryTreeNode<E> preorderFind(E data) {
        if(this.data.equals(data))
            return this;

        if(left != null){
            IBinaryTreeNode<E> leftResult = left.preorderFind(data);
            if(leftResult != null)
                return leftResult;
        }

        if(right != null){
            IBinaryTreeNode<E> rightResult = right.preorderFind(data);
            if(rightResult != null)
                return rightResult;
        }       

        return null;
    }

    // Postorder search (Left tree --> Right tree --> Node)
    @Override
    public IBinaryTreeNode<E> postorderFind(E data) {   

        if(left != null){
            IBinaryTreeNode<E> leftResult = left.preorderFind(data);
            if(leftResult != null)
                return leftResult;
        }

        if(right != null){
            IBinaryTreeNode<E> rightResult = right.preorderFind(data);
            if(rightResult != null)
                return rightResult;
        }       

        if(this.data.equals(data))
            return this;

        return null;
    }

}
```

And finally the Tree Implementation

```
public class BinaryTree<E extends Object> implements IBinaryTree<E> {

    IBinaryTreeNode<E> root;
    int size;

    public BinaryTree(IBinaryTreeNode<E> node){

        this.root = node;
        size++;
    }   

    @Override
    public IBinaryTreeNode<E> getRoot() {
        return root;
    }


    @Override
    public Boolean isEmpty() {
        return (size == 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void insert(E data) {

    }

}
```

Comment: If you want to compare objects of a generic type, you can just implement the Comparable compareTo(T o) method.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html